# NameError: name 'PI' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to create a Formula() function that takes as argument an algebraic formula (that uses Python syntax) and returns a new class. The constructor of that class takes as argument a string of comma-separated variable=value pairs. Finally, the class has a calc() method that evaluates its formula using the given variable values and prints the result.
Problem is here it will work:

```
triangle_hypotenuse = Formula('(a*a + b*b)**0.5')
print(triangle_hypotenuse('a=3, b=4') .calc())
```

but when i try:

```
cylinder_volume = Formula('PI * r**2 * h')
cylinder_volume('r= 1, h=2') .calc()
```

I get the error *NameError: name 'PI' is not defined* how can i make it reference the pi from the math module?

Here is my full code

```
import math
from math import pi,cos,sin,tan,atan

# eval('a + sin(p/2)', bindings)    # 'sin' not defined

def Formula(expression):
    class F:

        def __init__(self,kwargs):
            s = kwargs.replace(',','')
            l=((s.replace('=',' ').split()))

            it = iter(l)

            self.res_dct = dict(zip(it,it))
            self.res_dct=  {k:float(v) for k, v in self.res_dct.items()}

            class Foo:
                def setAllWithKwArgs(self, **kwargs):
                    for key, value in kwargs.items():
                        setattr(self, key, value)

        def calc(self):

            return eval(expression,self.res_dct)

    return F

triangle_hypotenuse = Formula('(a*a + b*b)**0.5')
print(triangle_hypotenuse('a=3, b=4') .calc())

cylinder_volume = Formula('PI * r**2 * h')
cylinder_volume('r= 1, h=2') .calc()
```

Comment: try `pi` in lowercase ?

Comment: `PI` isn't defined anywhere...

Comment: `eval()` is widely viewed with a certain amount of suspicion. Google "Python. eval is evil" for details. In contexts like this it doesn't really make a difference, but it is a bad habit to reach for `eval` when confronted with a parsing problem.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how can i reference the pi from the math module?

Comment: Because `pi` isn't `PI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) takes globals and locals, and you over-wrote globals. Additionally, you have `PI` in the wrong case. Try the following.

```py
def calc(self):
    return eval(expression.lower(), globals(), self.res_dct)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write PI as pi ..

Answer (score 0):

you are doing `eval` on string , so are doing math on string and `pi` is undefined